# Does Gurobipy exploits sparsity of the optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, gurobi, cvxpy

What happens when a (sparse) `csr` matrix / array is submitted to Gurobi (via Cvxpy framework in python).

Does it exploit the sparsity Information about the matrix or does everything gets converted to standard matrix / array?

Secondly, is there any drawback (especially in exploiting sparsity information), when calling Gurobi through Python vs calling through Matlab?

Comment: Drawbacks I do not know as I don't use matlab, but there is at least one good reason to use Python: it is free.

Comment: All the major optimization software packages only deals with sparse data.

Comment: Gurobipy doesn't know about scipy.sparse.csr (last time i checked) and therefore what counts is whats happening in the wrapper code. There are lots of potential approaches (e.g. a low-level standard-form like wrapping vs. modelling-language like wrapping), but sparsity will always be respected (as 99.9% of use-cases won't do without). As cvxpy is open-source you can check the wrappers yourself. | As for python vs. matlab: python probably won't be worse / less efficient as it's commonly seen as the most FFI-friendly language (opposed to Java for example where zero-copy interfaces are hard).